# Save and load different desktop files based on the mode

Tags: hooks, desktop, session

I would like to keep distinct desktop files in order to be able resume sessions based on the mode.

When I open Emacs it should load the desktop file for the mode it starts with and when I run, say, `M-x latex-mode` it should load (and later overwrite) another desktop file. In my noobness I had hoped a

```
(setq desktop-path '("~/.emacs.d/desktops/plain" ~/.emacs.d/desktops/latex-mode"))
(defun my-TeX-hook ()
  (desktop-change-dir "~/.emacs.d/desktops/latex-mode"))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'my-TeX-hook)
```

in my `.emacs` would work, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to do, if you use library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).

You can easily create any number of [desktop bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks), including multiple such in the same directory. And you can then easily switch to any of them just by "jumping" to its bookmark.

And you can of course jump to a bookmark, including a desktop bookmark, from a mode hook. E.g., use something like this on your mode hook, where `my-desktop-bmk-42` is the name of one of your desktop bookmarks:

```el
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook (lambda () (bookmark-jump "my-desktop-bmk-42")))
```

If you want to be sure your `bookmark-file` is already loaded (so `my-desktop-bmk-42` is defined), then use this:

```el
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (bookmark-maybe-load-default-file)
                           (bookmark-jump "my-desktop-bmk-42")))
```

You can of course define that function as a named function, or even as a command:

```el
(defun switch-to-desktop-42 ()
  "Jump to desktop bookmark `my-desktop-bmk-42'."
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-maybe-load-default-file)
  (bookmark-jump "my-desktop-bmk-42"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better than ideal. Now I'd like to ask you some questions :-) 1) Is `bookmarks+` compatible with `desktop`? I mean, can I tweak it by setting `desktop-save`, `desktop-path` and so on? 2) Can I set it up so that it auto-saves? Last thing, I tried `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'bmkp-desktop-save-as-last)` but it didn't work. Did I do something wrong or what?

Comment: Yes. Bookmark+ makes no changes to desktop.el code. You can autosave Emacs in a desktop, but you probably won't want to use that desktop for a bookmark. Use `bmkp-set-desktop-bookmark` (**`C-x p K`**) to set (create or update) a desktop as a particular bookmark. For your question about `bmkp-desktop-save-as-last` you will need to provide more detail: a step-by-step recipe to repro, explaining what you saw and what you expected to see instead. Send that to me as a bug report (that's not what emacs.SE is for): `M-x customize-group bookmark-plus`, then click the button/link **`Send Bug Report`**.